# how to target Google Play Search?

Tags: google-play-store

It is very annoying, that almost everytime I search for Apps (i.e. Go SMS, Handcent SMS, Viber, etc...)

in the results always show up i.e. "Go SMS silver theme", "Viber Smiles"....

so, the actual app i am searching for, never shows up in the top results..
what is the solution to this annoying cases..

Comment: Probably they paid advertisment of app (smiley's). Just like on facebook sponsored content

Comment: Pretty strange, have you installed those apps before? In which case you might need to remove them from your  "My Apps" list

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. this happens on the apps, that are not supported to my country, for unknown reason I have no idea. I've installed them manually from their site, by downloading APK.